# Converting XML field names to Excel columns

Tags: xml, excel, csv, xls

I don't have any experience with XML, but one of my e-commerce customers is having problems.

His ERP software outputs his products in the following fashion:

```
<Record>
<Field Name="column1" Value="Product1" />
<Field Name="column2" Value="20" />
<Field Name="column3" Value="30" />
</Record>
<Record>
<Field Name="column1" Value="Product2" />
<Field Name="column2" Value="40" />
<Field Name="column3" Value="50" />
</Record>
```

How can I import this XML file to Excel in a way that the result is a table such as:

Column1    Column2    Column3

Product1        20            30

Product2        40            50

And so on..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I guess this is the root of the original file, with one full product as sample:

```
StoreName=Store Name
StoreID=6743
UserName=1
Password=xxxxx
OutputFormat=1
method=ProductManagement
XMLRecords=<Records>
<Record>
<Field Name="Comando" Value="A" />
<Field Name="NomeCat" Value="BOTAS E MACACOES" />
<Field Name="IDProduto" Value="5159271" />
<Field Name="CodProd" Value="107239" />
<Field Name="NomeProd" Value="MACACAO NYLON - 44" />
<Field Name="Peso" Value="5000.00" />
<Field Name="Descricao" Value=""/>
<Field Name="DescrLonga" Value="Grade orientada pelo numero da bota."/>
<Field Name="Estoque" Value="0" />
<Field Name="EstoqueMinimo" Value="0" />
<Field Name="Preco" Value="198.45" />
<Field Name="ImagemProd" Value="107239.JPG" />
<Field Name="ImagemDet" Value="107239.JPG" />
<Field Name="ImagemAmp" Value="107239.JPG" />
<Field Name="Adicional3" Value="051933" />
</Record><Record>
```

Comment: Please show root of your XML, a very import piece as it can contain namespaces.

Comment: please check my edit, I'm not sure that is what you're asking for.

Comment: [Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) is XML 101. From your edit it would have been `<Records>`. However all the other text renders this NOT an XML document. Is this really the document? If so, before any coding, figure out why the ERP is not rendering well-formed XML.

Comment: @Parfait , Sorry for the delay in response. This is exactly what the ERP generates.

I don't mind changing *something* in the output file to make it work, as I already found out that if I change the 'field name' to the name itself, it works.

For example:

`<field name="NomeCat">1</field>`

does not work, but:

`<NomeCat>1</nomecat>`

works perfectly.

However, it's too work-intensive to manually rename all the fields.